# When the number of slides of my beamer is more than 10, the date is not displayed correctly in the inferior right corner

Tags: beamer, date, slideshow

When the number of slides of my beamer is more than 10, the date is not displayed correctly in the inferior right corner of my slides.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Madrid}       % or try default, Darmstadt, Warsaw, ...
  \usecolortheme{default} % or try albatross, beaver, crane, ...
  \usefonttheme{serif}    % or try default, structurebold, ...
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\definecolor{ao(english)}{rgb}{0.0, 0.5, 0.0}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{resize to}[%
  physical paper width=8in, physical paper height=6in]
\title[Unal%iversidad Nacional de Colombia
]{}
\author{Juan Muñoz
}

\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

% These three lines create an automatically generated table of contents.
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

¿How could I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with the following redefinition of the footline:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Madrid}       
%  \usecolortheme{default} as the name says, this is default
  \usefonttheme{serif}    
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{epstopdf} not needed with current tex distributions
\usepackage{comment}
%\usepackage{graphicx} not needed with beamer
\usepackage{subfig}

%\definecolor{ao(english)}{rgb}{0.0, 0.5, 0.0} Better not use () in colour names 

\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{resize to}[physical paper width=8in, physical paper height=6in]

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor\expandafter\ifblank\expandafter{\beamer@shortinstitute}{}{~~(\insertshortinstitute)}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hfill%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{page number in head/foot}\usebeamerfont{page number in head/foot}\makebox[0.9cm][r]{\usebeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}}\hspace*{2ex} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother

\title[Unal]{}
\author{Juan Muñoz}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

---

If you are using beamer v3.54 you could also use [this version of beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/blob/00addfbdaa7ba54190e2955c16659fb95a7cf28a/base/beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty) in which I fixed the problem.

Comment: When I copy your code to mine I dont know were I have to paste it because you erase a lot of things of my original code. However I past it before the command \begin{document}, and also try pasting it after the command \usepackage[spanish]{babel}, but none worked. Both showed me compiling errors. Where do I have to paste it?, also could you please add all the commands that my minimal working example had? !Thanks in advance!

Comment: @JuanMuñoz It does not matter where you put this in your preamble. Can you show which error message you get?

Comment: @JuanMuñoz I added all the packages which make sense with beamer

Comment: The error message is this "Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \ifblank 
                         
l.47 \begin{document}"

Comment: @JuanMuñoz Which version of beamer do you have?

Comment: @JuanMuñoz You'll need beamer version >= 3.50 to use my answer

Comment: I am working with overleaf. Are the beamer version diferently?

Comment: @JuanMuñoz i don't know which version is used by overleaf. You can look this up in the .log file.